# Can you execute javascript from within a custom Kentico global event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, kentico

Using version 10 of Kentico and trying to call javascript from within a custom event handler (authentication) that I created. Code is:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationModule: Module {
    // Module class constructor, the system registers the module under the name "CustomAuthentication"
    public CustomAuthenticationModule(): base("CustomAuthentication") {}

    // Contains initialization code that is executed when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit() {
        base.OnInit();

        // Assigns a handler to the SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute event
        // This event occurs when users attempt to sign in on the website
        SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute += OnAuthentication;
    }

    private void OnAuthentication(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs e) {
        // Checks if the user was authenticated by the default system. Only continues if authentication succeeded.
        if (e.User != null) {
            // Run client-side javascript function called UpdateCrisp

            // Testing only
            EventLogProvider.LogInformation("Crisp update on login", "INFORMATION", "Crisp update successful on login");

        }
    }
}
```

and the javascript is just something simple like:

```
function UpdateCrisp() {
    console.log("Contact updated");
}
```

I tried using RegisterClientScriptBlock and also tried adding an OnClientClick event to the LinkButton in the .ascx but because it is a user control and not a page it won't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to register a client-side script from a Kentico global system event, like SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute, because you will not have access to the ASP.NET Page. The system event may not be fired within the page's lifecycle.

How about creating a WebMethod that can be called from the client-side code to see if the user is successfully authenticated?

Mike

Comment: I guess I was just looking for confirmation of what I already thought to be true. Thanks. That’ll work as a solution.